# Updating values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Given These two tables:

```
         emp                              dept

------|--------|--------|    |--------|------------|----------|
empno |  name  | deptno |    | deptno |    dname   |    loc   |
------|--------|--------|    ----------------------|----------|
7566  | Jones  |   20   |    |   10   | Accounting | New York |
7654  | Martin |   30   |    |   20   | Research   | Dallas   |
7689  | Blake  |   30   |    |   30   | Sales      | Chicago  |
7782  | Clark  |   10   |    ----------------------------------
7839  | King   |   10   |
-------------------------
```

One of the questions is :

```
Employee 'Clark' has been transferred to the Sales department. Use 
the appropriate query to reflect this change in the amp table. Make 
use of a subquery to determine the department number of the Sales 
department.
```

(just discovered the data used in these tables is from sql cookbook)

Anyways I'm new to SQL , and I'm using MySQL to complete this question. I Thought about using an UPDATE query but I can't figure out how to incorporate the query for determining the department number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you would select the deptno for a sales position (you'd get 30 for Sales):

```
SELECT deptno
FROM dept
WHERE dname = 'Sales'
```

Then you would take this deptno and use it as the value you're going to set deptno to in emp for the person named Clark with empno = 7782:

```
UPDATE emp SET emp.deptno = 
    (SELECT dept.deptno
     FROM dept
     WHERE dname = 'Sales')
WHERE empno = 7782;
```

Comment: I get an error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE emp SET emp.deptno =
(SELECT dept.depno
FROM dept
WHERE dname = "Sales")
' at line 4

Comment: So your column name in one of your tables is "depno" instead of "deptno"?  So it's working after the small change?

Comment: No just altered the table and I'm still getting the error,, even recreated the database.

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle with my query and a really hastily created schema and data insert http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5e8c/1.  It should work unless your empno is potentially a VARCHAR or something that requires quotations around it.  Could you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm using mysql on mac book pro (mid 2010) , os x el capitan 10.11.5 and I managed to get it to work by just using the second part of the query; starting from UPDATE so al is well. 

Thank You Dresden!!